# Forcing images to dynamically resize to container/browser height with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, resize

Basically I'm looking to get my horizontal scrolling sites (using indexhibit) images to be relative to browser size. 
At the moment using the following code it seems to resize the height but not the width?

This is my javascript that I found from this thread http://www.indexhibit.org/forum/thread/11531 which I've attached in an external js doc.

```
function resizeit() { showHeight('document', $(window).height());
function showHeight(ele, h) {
$('.picture img').css( 'height', h -30 );
$('#img-container').css( 'height', h -30 );

}
var    sum = 0;
$('.picture img').each(function() 
{ 
sum += $(this).width() +21;

}); 
$('#img-container').width( sum );    
}

$(window).resize(function() {

resizeit();
});

$(window).load(function(){
resizeit();
});
```

And this is my PHP

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='{{baseurl}}/ndxzsite/js/images.js<last:page:version     
/>'></script>

<last:page:css />
<last:page:onready />
<plugin:backgrounder />
</head>
<body class='{{object}} section-{{section_id}} exhibit-{{id}} format-{{format}}'>
<div class="header">
<h1><a href='/' title='{{obj_name}}'><img src="files/lucy-bower-logo.png" alt="lucy bower logo"></a></div>
<div id='index'>

<div class='menu'>

<div class='top'>{{obj_itop}}</div>
<plugin:index:load_index />
<div class='bot'><p>© Lucy bower 2014</p> <p>Built by <a href="http://www.neptik.com">Neptik</a></p>
{{obj_ibot}}</div>

<last:page:append_index />
</div>
</div>

<div id='exhibit'>
<div class='container'>

<div class='top'><!-- --></div>
<!-- text and image -->
<plugin:page:exhibit />
<!-- end text and image -->

</div>
</div>
<plugin:page:append_page />
<plugin:page:closing />
</body>
```

And my images end up sitting in a stack like this [image: html and css stack![][1]]

I just don't really understand what I'm doing wrong if it's worked for other people :( is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sizing the img tag, I would personally recommend making the image file the background-image of the parent div ie.

```
<div style="background-image=url('locationofImage.png'); background-size:cover;"></div>
```

> background-image:url(''); - Sets the background image
>
> background-size:cover; - Set how the image should fill the div

This will simply position the image in the background of the div to ensure there is no whitespace. You then can using css set the height and width of the div to fit the space you need.

Comment: Thing is, it's a cms so the images are uploaded as images into those divs. How would I translate this across

Comment: Have you got access to the images src value, the location its stored?

Comment: Yeah I do actually, they all seem to get put into a gimgs folder once I upload through the CMS filepath - local/ndxzsite/files/dimgs/

Comment: You would place in the public location of the url into the style/css tag ie `style="background-image=url('./files/dimgs/locationofImage.png'); background-size:cover;"`

Answer (score 0):

I'am not really sure if you can use it. But the whole layout can be done with CSS alone, here is an example.

**Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Zz5/1/**

```
*
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.wrap
{
    overflow-x: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.left
{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.item
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: -4px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.item img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.item:before
{
    display: inline-block;
    content:"";
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: inherit;
}


/* First Item width - nav width */
.left + .item
{
    width: calc( 100% - 200px );
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.item:nth-child(2){
    background-color: yellow;
}

.item:nth-child(3){
    background-color: purple;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        <ul>
            <li>Nav</li>
            <li>Nav</li>
            <li>Nav</li>
            <li>Nav</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="item"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x800" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x100" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/1000x800" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but something seems to be overriding it?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about @SofiSmith. When you have implemented this in your page and it's not working, you have not changed your HTML structure to the one in the demo, or you have not changed the selectors as required for your page. It's not a plug- and play solution, you will have to refactor a good portion or your existing code. Your current CSS can override it or the Js-Libs you were talking about.

Comment: Thank you for your help @nicoO, I understand this and it should work but I think some php is controlling the CSS elsewhere as my images still have their absolute height - I will endeavour - I will never use indexhibit again :(

Comment: I don't think you PHP will do this. It' more likely a JS issue. Have you tried to remove the indexhibit .js files for a test?